# How to repair this shower/bathroom wall for bathroom remodel.

Tags: bathroom, remodeling, renovation

I have a nasty bathroom downstairs. It looks like the previous owners built it over a floor drain, not entirely sure if this is a good thing or not (not even sure if that's what they did but see attached photos for the washer height knobs).

Obvious water damage behind the shower area. Needs to be gutted and rebuilt.

I just don't exactly know where to start or what are the obvious noob mistake that will cost me later.

I'm comfortable with soldering, drywall, tiling,etc. I've never built a  wall or frame before so I probably need the most guidance there.

Any help is appreciated. Good books or other references would be awesome.

Specific question: Are there any specific issues that might cause bigger problems later on (from first answer full stud replacement vs patch) when I repair/replace this wall?

Photos:
[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12318974/IMG_20130313_230047.jpg]
[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12318974/IMG_20130313_230054.jpg]
<sup>Click for larger view</sup>

Comment: sorry for the blur, didn't realize it was this bad until now.

Comment: @Tester101 did you shrink these and re-upload them?

Comment: This question may be a bit too broad, and could possibly solicit extended discussion and will likely not have a single *correct* answer.

Comment: Broad questions get broad answers! To get specific we could write a few DiY books on this.

Comment: If you add `m` to the end of the imgur link, a medium size image is displayed (`http://i.stack.imgur.com/9tpXIm.jpg` see the `m`?). If you then surround the image markup with link markup, you can make the image clickable (`[![enter image description here][3]](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sm0TT.jpg)`)

Comment: I know this is broad, and being a fairly active SO user, I kinda know what happens, but I need the help on where to start, which books are good reference,etc.

Comment: @cbrulak [DIY.StackExchange.com](http://diy.stackexchange.com/) is a great resource, the community there is very helpful when you ask specific questions.

Comment: On a side note: I didn't make the images smaller, I made everything else bigger.

Comment: Added a specific question.

Comment: @cbrulak For the specific question, are you asking why use full-length studs instead of patching rotten parts?

Comment: No, i just wanted to reference that point from your question because it is direct and of those gotchas that should be pointed out :)

Comment: Hell, I could write a book on bathroom remodel.  You need to decide on what type of fixtures, wall finishes, lighting, flooring etc. Each of these choices are going to effect how you build this bathroom.  Break it down for us a bit.

Comment: Okay, i know that all that stuff is a huge job and can't be answered here. My goal: fix that wall and fixtures so that I can put in a basic shower. I'm not worried about the pipes/plubming or tiling or drywall so however we decided shouldn't affect this question, which is specifically how to repair/replace this wall,etc. (i'll update the question with that ) Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Replace all the drywall, frame the wall at 16'OC, install horizontal supports for the plumbing, insulate it and add a vapor barrier, then use MR rock, then install the shower stall.

Comment: elementary summed up in 1 sentence by shirlock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A floor drain is no problem in a bathroom, in fact that's a bonus! Just don't let it dry up.

As for where to start, here is a general guideline:

1. Tear out all the drywall and to expose any rotten areas.
2. Replace rotten studs, one at a time (full-length, don't patch). You don't won't to remove a whole wall at once, it may be load-bearing. Put in temporary studs for any iffy areas.
3. Fix the plumbing.
4. Choose your shower-surround (tile, fibreglass, etc...) and finish accordingly.

Also, whichever product you choose for waterproofing your shower will usually have their own specifications on how to waterproof on their websites. For example: [Kerdi](http://www.schluter.com/media/ShowerHandbook-2012-2013.pdf?v=201303142107) and [Nobleseal](http://www.noblecompany.com/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=Fu965kTFqOE=&tabid=66&mid=445). These two companies also have very helpful technical support departments and local sales reps.

*An example of an "iffy area":* If there are multiple studs all really rotten next to eachother and you are taking out one to replace it, the remaining load of the floor/roof over your head is now on all those rotten studs... That is an iffy situation, in my opinion.

Comment: 2: links for that? how would i know if it is iffy? I guess I can use the door as I guide (same wall). Thanks

Comment: e.g. If there are multiple studs all really rotten next to eachother and you are taking out one to replace it, the remaining load of the floor/roof over your head is now on all those rotten studs... That is an iffy situation, in my opinion.

Comment: point 4: MR drywall is no longer approved for showers: Water-resistant gypsum backing board shall not be installed over a vapor barrier in a shower or 
tub compartment. (R702.3.8.1)
 Water-resistant gypsum backing board shall not be used where there will be direct exposure to 
water, or in areas subject to continuous high humidity, such as saunas, steam rooms, indoor 
pools, etc. (R702.3.8.1)

Comment: @HerrBag which zone/code is that from? I'm sure there are national standards but aren't there local codes too?

Comment: You should not be relying on drywall for waterproofing a shower.

Comment: IRC 2009.  Don't EVER let someone tile directly on drywall MR or otherwise (for wet areas, inside showers). I use a waterproof membrane system, there are many: Schluter, Noble  and liquid membrane systems Hydroban, among many others

Comment: Yes, exactly, but I feel this is getting too specific for the question. We could add things all day. When he wants to waterproof the shower he should use a product like kerdi or nobleseal, or a fibreglass surround, but he hasn't even dealt with the rot yet.

Comment: I edited #4 to depend on your tub-surround choices. You can get into a waterproofing debate on which product to use when you get that far. Although generally MR drywall is fine in most cases. If you waterproof then it is not being exposed to water. Although, I prefer to use green e-board>kerdi>tile myself (not to be mistaken with greenboard).

Answer (score 1):

You must remove all water damaged drywall.

You should replumb/reframe for proper support of the wall covering (right now, it looks like the piece you tore off spanned over 30"..  way too far).   The valve should be setback into the stud cavity, unless you are going to use a shower enclosure.  If the pipes are where you want them, put studs on either side of the water supply.

Comment: nice catch on stud spacing. I'd stick with the standard spacing of 16" O.C. especially if tiling.  Could just be a camera perspective thing though.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done so yet make a list of what you liked and disliked and are willing to change in the original space. Expose as much of the space as you can. Plan your repairs, studs, wiring, plumbing etc with your final goal in mind. You don't want to replace a stud and find out later that it is where you want the shower valve. Also the shower system, fiberglass,tile, etc will all have varied framing requirements so you must have a general plan in place at the start.